# Page.xaml as a model for other pages

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new in a Xamarin development. I hope that you can resolve my problem in a simple mode.

I've a crossplatform app developed with Xamarin and in this app I've a page.xaml with a label. I use the binding to page.xaml.cs for the text.

**I want to use the page.xaml as a model for the design and I want to create other pages: page2, page3, page4, etc using the model of page1 but with the text binding of page2.xaml.cs, page3.xaml.cs, page4.xaml.cs, etc.**

So the hypothetical three of the app are this:

**Pagemodel.xaml** (the layout of all pages)

- **Page1.xaml.cs** (with the layout of pagemodel but the text of page1)
- **Page2.xaml.cs** (with the layout of pagemodel but the text of page2)
- **Page3.xaml.cs** (with the layout of pagemodel but the text of page3)

**I want this because in this way if i want to change the design of all the pages I simply modify the design of pagemodel.**

Plese, if you can, give me a simply solution or if you have other idea give me other solution for my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want this because in this way if i want to change the design of all the pages I simply modify the design of pagemodel.

**Pagemodel.xaml (the layout of all pages)**

An easy way is to do this with custom control. I make the control with three labels for example.

```
     <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding Country}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding Address}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
  </StackLayout>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**Page.xaml.cs (with the layout of pagemodel but the text of page)**

Same way to binding the data with the same view model.

```
ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel()
        {
            Name = "A",
            Address = "A-Address",
            Country = "A-Country"
        };

        this.BindingContext = viewModel;
```

Usage of Custom Control

`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PageModelDemo.Views"`

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <local:Page></local:Page>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

[image]

You could download from PageModelDemo folder on Github.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the BindingContext through the new page constructor or you can bind a static model on original page and call it from another pages

MainPage

```
        public static YourModel BindingC;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            this.BindingContext = YourClass;
            YourModel = YourClass;


        }
```

SecondPage

```
 public SecondPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            this.BindingContext = MainPage.YourModel;



        }
```

Another alternative

SecondPage

```
public SecondPage(BindingC = null)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if(BindingC != null)
               this.BindingContext = BindingC;


        }
```

Mainpage

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SecondPage(your binding context));


        }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Can you give me an example with code? Just for understand

Comment: really sorry...but i can't understand how i can do it. can you give me an example that work so i can see the results? sorry for that

Comment: i dont know if you understand my question. I want to design the pagemodel using xaml but i want that the text content is different in page1, page2, page3, etc and every pages is based on the pagemodel